# Stack using Linked List says stack has no attribute as head

Tags: python-2.7, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement Stack using LinkedList in Python .I have written the following code :

```
class Node:


    def __init__(self):
            self.data = None
            self.next = None

    def getData(self):
            return self.data

    def getNext(self):
            return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
            self.data = newdata



    def setNext(self,newnext):
            self.next = newnext



class Stack :


    def _init_(self):
        self.head=None


    def push(self,data):

        temp=Node()
        temp.setData(data)
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head=temp

    def pop(self):

        temp=Node()
        temp=self.getData()
        self.head=self.head.getNext()
        return temp
```

But when i try to push a data item to a stack , i get an error message

"AttributeError: Stack instance has no attribute 'head'". Kindly help in understanding what is going wrong .

Comment: `__init__()` is spelled with two leading and trailing underscores, not one.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That helped .